# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call - GWT

Tags: gwt

I am facing an error while running my GWT application.

```java
public abstract class BaseDAOImpl<T> implements BaseDAO<T> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;
@Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        List<T> results = null;
        Query query = null;
        try{
            query = pm.newQuery(persistentClass); [Error Line]
            results = (List<T>) query.execute();
            results = (List<T>) pm.detachCopyAll(results);
        }finally{
            pm.close();
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Showing me Error as following:

> [ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletContext
>   log: Exception while dispatching
>   incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException:
>   Service method 'public abstract
>   java.util.List
>   com.aamjanta.webapp.client.service.StoreService.getStoreList()'
>   threw an unexpected exception:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen
>   space     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)

---

> [ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletContext
>   log: Exception while dispatching
>   incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException:
>   Service method 'public abstract
>   java.util.List
>   com.aamjanta.webapp.client.service.StoreService.getStoreList()'
>   threw an unexpected exception:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOMetaDataManager
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

---

> [ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletContext
>   log: Exception while dispatching
>   incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException:
>   Service method 'public abstract
>   java.util.List
>   com.aamjanta.webapp.client.service.CouponService.getCouponList()'
>   threw an unexpected exception:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class
>   org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOMetaDataManager
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GWT isn't expecting your server side to fail with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen", which usually happens when your server JVM doesn't have enough memory to JIT-compile classes into.

(Use -XX:MaxPermSize=128m to increase the size of the Perm space).

Answer (score 0):

in second line you declared  `private Class<T> persistentClass;`

and  later you are using  that in below line

```
query = pm.newQuery(persistentClass); [Error Line]
```

where you are intializing that ??

```
persistentClass = ?
```